# How to prove it's not a gaussian vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Good morning,

I am stuck on a question. Basically, I have 2 random variables, $X = (0;1)$and B is a rademarcher variable. $X$ and $B$ are independent. I already proved that $XB = (0;1)$.
But I don't really know how to prove that (X,XB) is not a gaussian vector...

I tried this :
$
W = X+X = X(1+). x ∈ R :$

$P(W ⩽ x) = P(X(1+)⩽ x)$ =$\frac{1}{2}[P(2X⩽ x $ and $ (1+) = 2 ) + P(0 ⩽ x$ and $(1+B) = 0]$
We have in the end :

$\frac{1}{2}[1 +  P(2X⩽ x]$ if $ x $⩾0

$\frac{1}{2}[P(2X⩽ x ] $ if $x <0 $

In fact, I don't know how to conclude.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

$(X,XB)$ is not Gaussian because $X+XB$ is not Gaussian: $P(X+XB=0)=P(B=-1)=\frac  1 2$. Since  Gaussian distributin is continuous this cannot happen.

Comment: Hi ! 
Sorry I did not write the right conditions...
I edited my message

Comment: @AFrenchstudent Did you read my answer fully? I had already answered the new version of your question also.